# (ubuntu) How to kill a respawn service

Tags: ubuntu, inittab

I like to *respawn* a service when the service goes down. I have added it to *inittab* however I cannot kill it when i need to.

Is there away i can *respawn* a service however be able to kill it manually when i need to.

thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has switched to [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) for its `init` daemon, so the best way would be to make an Upstart job file in `/etc/init/`. Here's an example:

```
description "My important service"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec /usr/bin/mydaemon --some-args
```

If this file is saved as `/etc/init/myjob.conf`, it will create a job that starts at boot, respawns when it dies, and can be manually stopped (as root) with `stop myjob`, `service myjob stop`, or `initctl stop myjob`.

Comment: ...what if he's running a pre-upstart version of Ubuntu? :)

Comment: @voretaq7 Then he should upgrade, because the last version that didn't have Upstart was 6.06LTS (dapper), which stopped being supported in 2009 (2011 for servers).

Comment: Prior to 10.04LTS (lucid), the Upstart directory was `/etc/event.d/`, but those versions are also no longer supported. Here's a handy resource for [Ubuntu end-of-life dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions).

Answer (score 1):

### Non-Upstart systems

Old-school use of `/etc/inittab`. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?inittab+5

The basic format is

```
<uniqueid>:<runlevel>:<action>:<command>
```

### Upstart systems

Modern use of `.conf` files in `/etc/init/`: http://linux.die.net/man/5/init

The `inittab` method from above will still work.

Comment: For completeness, one of the most common init schemes is sysvinit, which consists of scripts in /etc/init.d/, symlinked from the appropriate /etc/rc[RUNLEVEL].d/, frequently configured with update-rc.d.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried solutions presented in previous answers, but it didn't work for my version of Teamviewer 9. The only way how to stop `teamviewerd` from respawning was this:

`killall -9 teamviewerd`

Comment: op is talking about respawn from init. You can't kill init. You can do what the accepted answer says, or on SystemV system, edit inittab, then `init q` or `telinit q`